# Me encontré con un problema al querer obtener el precio mínimo de un repuesto

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
def Buscar(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    Marca = request.POST.get('marca')
    Modelo = request.POST.get('modelo')
    Año = request.POST.get('año')
    nombre_repuesto = request.POST.get('nombre_repuesto')
    buscarR= Repuesto.objects.raw('Select re.id ,MIN(re.Costo),ve.marca, ve.modelo, ve.año, re.nombre_repuesto from vehiculos_vehiculo as ve inner join repuestos_repuesto as re on re.Fk_vehiculo_id = ve.id where re.Garantia ="N"  and ve.marca="'+str(Marca)+'" and ve.modelo="' +str(Modelo)+'" and ve.año = "'+str(Año)+'" and re.nombre_repuesto = "'+str(nombre_repuesto)+'"')
    return render(request, 'Buscar.html',{"Repuesto":buscarR})
else:
    Objeto = Repuesto.objects.raw('Select re.id ,ve.marca, ve.modelo, ve.año, re.nombre_repuesto from vehiculos_vehiculo as ve inner join repuestos_repuesto as re on re.Fk_vehiculo_id = ve.id') 
    return render(request, 'Buscar.html',{"Repuesto":Objeto})
```

Esta es mi funcion para buscar y enviar los valores a mi html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que muestra en la imagen son todos mis repuestos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al momento de buscar un repuesto

El problema es que no me toma el menor valor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si no el que se encuentra primero en mi base de datos
Si me pueden ayudar seria de gran ayuda gracias.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien cual es el error, puedes poner un pantallazo?

Comment: El error que veo es la indentación. El `if` al mismo nivel que la función y no en el siguiente . Ahorrate problemas no uses ñ en variables.

Comment: @Krengifo ya le edite para que le entiendas mejor, gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intentar hace un `Order by desc` y `limit 1`.

E intenta primero colocar la Query en un gestor o aparte del código, para ver si te funciona.